# GWT Blank page when using a GWT Library

Tags: java, gwt

I've been trying to use this [GWT Library](http://git.io/iM8ZWw), however my app compiles with no error the GWT shows blank page when this is used.

If someone would have some time to test this out also and see if it works, would really appreciate it.

The use for the library is very simple:

```
    String prettyTime = new TimeAgo().timeAgo(longDate);
```

If I remove this line the app works fine.

**Update:**

Also if I just add the Java files from the GWT library into the project the TimeAgo library works fine.

Comment: What TimeAgo class looks like ?

Comment: The code is quite long you can view it here: http://git.io/rZvLhg

Comment: suggest you look in the browser developer tools (F12 in chrome or IE, or use a plugin like firebug in firefox). This will likely show errors in the console or networking errors that may provide hints.

Comment: I've just created a new project and tested the class and it's working fine (GWT 2.5.1). It could be an error that you missed in GWT log. I use new Date().getTime() for longDate value.